# How can I reorder a select list on the fly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my application, I have an HTML select box from which I remove and add items based on various user actions (the items become available/unavailable). However, I would also like all items to be displayed in preferred order, so every time I return an item to the select list, I need to re-sort in preferred order and select the preferred option. I've been unsuccessful thus far.

This is what I've got currently:

```
    function update_select (select_id) {
        // Rebuild given select box with appropriate options
        var s = $(select_id);
        s.empty();
        for (index in order_by_kind(selectable)) {
            var option = selectable[index];
            var s_option = $('<option value="' + option.value + '">' + option.desc + '</option>')
            s.append(s_option);
            if (index == 0) {
              s_option.attr('selected', true);
              console.log(s_option);
            }
        }
    }
```

If I log the results of `order_by_kind()`, the option values are sorted as desired. I empty the contents of the list and rebuild it in the desired order, but the item always is last in the list. Logging `s_option` shows that the option is set as selected, but the item is never selected in the UI. What might I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

My `order_by_kind()` function is below, for those who would like to verify that it functions correctly:

```
    function order_by_kind(obj_list) {
        var tmp = [];
        for (index in type_order) {   
          var kind = type_order[index];
          for (obj_index in obj_list) {
            var obj = obj_list[obj_index]
            if (kind == obj.value) {
              tmp.push(obj);
              // break out of the inner loop
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        return tmp
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that although I was iterating over the ordered list, I was still referencing the unsorted list in order to build my options.

```
function update_select (select_id) {
    // Rebuild given select box with appropriate options
    var s = $(select_id);
    s.empty();
    // sort and write back the selectable items
    selectable = order_by_kind(selectable);
    for (index in selectable) {
        var option = selectable[index];
        var s_option = $('<option value="' + option.value + '">' + option.desc + '</option>')
        s.append(s_option);
        if (index == 0) {
          s_option.attr('selected', true);
          console.log(s_option);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, storing and restoring the selected value:

```
function update_select (select_id) {
    // Rebuild given select box with appropriate options
    var s = $(select_id);
    var val = s.val();
    s.empty();
    for (index in order_by_kind(selectable)) {
        var option = selectable[index];
        var s_option = $('<option value="' + option.value + '">' + option.desc + '</option>')
        s.append(s_option);
    }
    s.val(val);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I just end up a blank first element, with my options following, still in the wrong order.

Comment: @vezult - Can you post your `order_by_kind` method so I can do a quick test?  Also, do you always want to just select the first item in the list after the sort?

Comment: I actually think I found the problem (see my answer below), but I'll post that too, just for completeness. With regards to the second question; Yes, if the list is ordered properly, the first item should be the preferred option.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a dead question, however its the first one in the search results - So i will post my solution here: The fiddle contains the compare functions for both value and html.

```
function reOrderOptions(select)
{ 
    function compareOptions(optionA, optionB) {
        return optionA.value - optionB.value;
    }
var options = $(select + " option");
$(select).empty().append(options.sort(compareOptions));
}
```

[Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/ApKxA/4/)